# discrete mathematics relations a^-1=~a

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

i need help understanding a discrete mathematic question/solution.
The question is to see if there is a relation "a" on a not empty set "A", and a^-1=~a is true.

At the beginning, our teacher started by taking a random x, so that x is element of A, and there were two cases, first one, (x,x) is element of a, second one, (x,x) is not element of a. So, here's the deal, i have no idea why she specifically chose (x,x) and why not, for example, (x,y)? Can somebody tell me why, when do i choose (x,x) and when (x,y). Thank you. Here's the full solution:

1) (x,x)e a;
(x,x)e a <=> (x,x)e a^-1<=> (x,x)e ~a <=>(x,x)not e a, which is contradiction.
2) (x,x)not e a;
(x,x)not e a<=>(x,x) e ~a <=> (x,x)e a^-1 <=> (x,x)e a, which is contradiction.
The hipothesis that there is a e AXA, where a^-1 = ~a, is not true.

Comment: He choose $(x,x) \in a$ exactly because from it we may derive: $(x,x) \in a^{-1}$. Remember that  $(x,y) \in a$ **iff** $(y,x) \in a^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay, i thought that it may be case, thank you.